# Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I know this is the most commonly asked question but i am really looking for some help here as i don't understand what i am doing wrong here .

I have a generated a devise user and intend to create a gallery for users . Following is the code i have tried

Model - Gallery.rb

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Controller - galleries_controller.rb

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_gallery, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @galleries = Gallery.all
    respond_with(@galleries)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@gallery)
  end

  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @gallery = Gallery.new
    respond_with(@gallery)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'Gallery was successfully created.' if @gallery.save
    respond_with(@gallery)
  end

  def update
    flash[:notice] = 'Gallery was successfully updated.' if @gallery.update(gallery_params)
    respond_with(@gallery)
  end

  def destroy
    @gallery.destroy
    respond_with(@gallery)
  end

  private
    def set_gallery
      @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    end

    def gallery_params
      params[:gallery, :user_id]
    end
end
```

Folowing is the error that gets shown with better errors -
[image]

Logs

```
Started GET "/galleries/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-03 15:24:10 +0530
Processing by GalleriesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Gallery Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "galleries".* FROM "galleries" WHERE "galleries"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 63ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Gallery with 'id'=1:
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/core.rb:154:in `find'
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'visitors#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users do
     resources :galleries
     resources :photos
  end   
end
```

As i am still new to ROR , any help would be very much appreciated . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you paste params over here?

Comment: gallery_params ? That's there in the code already

Comment: Nope from server log. which hash you are getting i think you are not getting user_id over there

Comment: Can you share your route file?

Comment: Updated with the routes

Comment: Then your URL should be localhost:3000/users/<user_id>/galleries/gallery_id for show

Comment: I retracted back to my old routes and as suggested by you ,  the current_user works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the URL i am assuming you are not passing user_id in params.

In your route file gallery should be nested route. If you wan't user_id.

```
resources :users do
  resources :galleries do
  end
end
```

or you can use

```
@user= current_user
```

Comment: Then your route should be like that or use current_user.id

Comment: ok , thanks i have changed my routes accordingly as i will be needing the user_id .

Comment: @GhostBuster you should use `@gallery = current_user.galleries.new`, this will handle the association, the created gallery will have the `user_id` in it by default.